# Configure RAID for IBM X3630 X3

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, ibm, ibm-xseries

How can I setup a RAID for IBM X3630 X3 server with IBM ServeRAID M5015 disk drives?
Is there a tool to configure disk drives? I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the IBM MegaRAID software from [HERE](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5073015) and read the user manual on the same page.

Comment: Could you please answer [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/353782/read-smart-status-on-windows-server-2008-r2) question too?

Answer (score 0):

2nd option: reboot and go into MegaRAID BIOS - either via UEFI setup (F1) or pressing Ctrl-H when MR BIOS is initializing.