# Read SMART status on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: ibm, smart, ibm-xseries

How can I read my hard drives SMART status on Windows Server 2008 R2?

I'm using IBM X3630 X3 server with IBM ServeRAID M5015 disk drives

Comment: What is the RAID config, if any?

Comment: 2 disks in RAID-1 for OS, other 10 disks are placed as separated drives - 10 RAID-0 volumes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MegaRAID controllers will generate alert when disk SMART/PFA is tripped.  W2008 retrieves controller alerts quite nicely and places them in System event log.
If you want to look at disk statistics, use MR software from here
http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5073015